# Javascript Get a random number but never the same

Tags: javascript, random

I am looking to get a random number beetween 0 and an array length which contain objects. It's almost working but the number I get is "undefined" sometimes and I don't understand why.

Here my code :

```
var temp, stock = [];
var x = 
        [{'a' :' aa'},{'b ':'qsdf'},{'c':'aaa'},{'d':'ccc'},{'e':'54'},{'f':'l'},
         {'a' :' bb'},{'b ':'qsdf'},{'c':'aaa'},{'d':'ccc'},{'e':'54'},{'f':'l'}];

function randomize(min,max) {
    return Math.floor((Math.random()*max)+min);
}

function test(tab) {

    var tabLength = tab.length;

    if(stock.length == tabLength ) {

        alert('End')

    }else{

         temp = randomize(0,tabLength); 

        if(stock.length == 0) {

            stock += temp;
            return temp;

        }else{  

            if(stock.indexOf(temp) > -1)  {

                test(tab);

            }else{

                stock += temp;
                return temp;                
            }       
        }
    }
}



    div.onclick = function () {
        var number = test(x)
        alert(stock+' '+number)
```

}

Comment: shuffle the array and pop() a single answer. pop() again to get new answers, never repeating.

Comment: @dandavis thanks for your answer. How can I use the property of an objet that I 'd just pop(). In this case, if I do var newObj = x.pop() then when I do alert(newObj.a) I get "undefined"..

Comment: not all your object have an "a" property, they are hetrogenous. i belive your data is structured incorrectly for what you want to do, but it's hard to tell from where i'm sitting...

Comment: @dandavis oh yes sorry my mistake..